# How to show title on apex:outputPanel

Tags: visualforce

How do you display title on `apex:outputPanel` and in my particular scenario I can not use `pageBlock` due to this issue [see here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148839/trouble-positioning-formatting-pageblock-side-by-side-using-panelgrid).

I also tried using `<apex:facet` but did not do anything.

Here is the code:

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" width="100%"> 
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op1" title="aaa">  
           <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O56300000aAsb"   
                showRefreshButton="true"/>   
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op2" title="bbb">  
          <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O34000000aAnb"  
               showRefreshButton="true" /> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just directly put html tags inside it to use it as a title:

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" width="100%"> 
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op1" title="aaa"> 
           <h2>aaa</h2>
           <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O56300000aAsb"   
                showRefreshButton="true"/>   
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op2" title="bbb">  
          <h2>bbb</h2>
          <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O34000000aAnb"  
               showRefreshButton="true" /> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

Please note that title in apex:outputPanel is only the display information which displays when your mouse hovers over it. It is not the actual title.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more than two outputPanels; the table is generated dynamically using as many rows as necessary to satisfy the columns attribute:

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="2" border="0" width="100%"> 
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; display: block">Title 1</h1>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; display: block">Title 2</h1>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op1" title="aaa">  
           <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O56300000aAsb"   
                showRefreshButton="true"/>   
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="op2" title="bbb">  
          <analytics:reportChart reportId="00O34000000aAnb"  
               showRefreshButton="true" /> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

Comment: does not show the align: center

Comment: @NickKahn I just tested it in my org, it just needed a minor tweak. Try new the version.

Comment: thanks I see it now in center but is there a way to put the apex:outputpanel in the center of the page? like those two outputpanel i have is all the way to left, is there a way to make it center of the page and divide the width of each to be 50%